# FlowType type coverage not displaying in nuclide

Tags: flowtype, nuclide-editor

I have uninstalled -> installed nuclide and flow, but type coverage is not displaying [as expected](https://nuclide.io/docs/languages/flow/#type-coverage)

[image]

- Toggling it in Nuclide/Type Coverage/Toggle Inline display is not
  working
- Using the keyboard shortcut isn't working as well

flow version = "Flow, a static type checker for JavaScript, version 0.26.0"

flow-bin: "^0.40.0"

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Flow is crashing. The topmost Flow error is an internal error which is concerning.

It's likely that Nuclide is running your system-wide Flow (v0.26.0), which is very old. You can upgrade that, or, under the settings for Flow in Nuclide, check the box to use the flow-bin binary for your project. Then it will use your project-local flow-bin install.

Comment: This did it for me, "check the box to use the flow-bin binary for your project. Then it will use your project-local flow-bin install." Thanks! :D